# Unit test project - NUnit reference, throw exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have unit test project and I wrote one test to check one functionality:

```
[Test]
    public async Task should_not_be_able_register_user_when_user_with_given_name_already_exists()
    {
        var mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();

        var userService = new UserService(mockUserRepository.Object);

        mockUserRepository.Setup(x => x.AddAsync(user));
        await userService.RegisterAsync("user", "userLastName", "fakeuser", "user@example.com", "123456789");
    }
```

In this test I want to check when user exist throw my defined exception but I have problems.

1. When I invoke await userService.RegisterAsync... how write assert ?

   Assert.Throws(() => what should be here ?

My code:
RegisterAsync looks like:

```
public async Task RegisterAsync(string firstName, string lastName, string username, string email, string phoneNumber)
    {
        var user = await _userRepository.GetAsync(username);

        if (user != null)
        {
            throw new CoreException(ErrorCode.UsernameExist, $"Username {user.Username} already exist.");
        }

        user = new User(firstName, lastName, username, email, phoneNumber);
        await _userRepository.AddAsync(user);
    }
```

GetAsync:

```
public async Task<User> GetAsync(string username)
        => await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == username);
```

Comment: You should only be asking one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the mock to return a `User`

```
//...

User user = new User("firstName", "lastName", "username", "email", "phoneNumber");
mockUserRepository
    .Setup(x => x.GetAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(() => user);


//...
```

so that

```
if (user != null)
{
    throw new CoreException(ErrorCode.UsernameExist, $"Username {user.Username} already exist.");
}
```

will cause the subject code to throw the expected error and asserted.

This can all be summarized as

```
[Test]
public async Task should_not_be_able_register_user_when_user_with_given_name_already_exists() {
    //Arrange
    var mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();

    var userService = new UserService(mockUserRepository.Object);

    User user = new User("firstName", "lastName", "username", "email", "phoneNumber");
    mockUserRepository
        .Setup(x => x.GetAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(() => user);

    //Act
    Func<Task> act = userService.RegisterAsync("user", "userLastName", "fakeuser", "user@example.com", "123456789");

    //Assert
    CoreException exception = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<CoreException>(act);
}
```